# Which Earth-616 Marvel character has the highest kill count?

Tags: marvel, kill-count

In the Marvel universe, there are a lot of heroes who kill their opponents quite regularly. We occasionally see questions about this aspect of the universe - such as "How many people has Daredevil killed?", "How many people has Wolverine killed?", etc. In addition, I found an old question that was closed because it was entirely too broad (link at bottom). So all of this inspired me to ask a more specific question:

**Which Earth-based character in Marvel's Earth-616 universe has the highest kill count?**

Please keep the following requirements in mind for any answer:

- The character must reside primarily on Earth (No Galactus, Thanos, or Silver Surfer)
- The character must reside in the Earth-616 universe
- The character can be either a hero OR a villain
- The kills must have occurred due to a direct act or plan by the character

Inspired by [Which DC (or Marvel) comic book HERO has killed the most bad guys?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24428/20557)

Comment: Your reference question was closed as not constructive. What do you think will happen to this question?

Comment: Does this include Jean Grey/Phoenix Force destroying an entire universe?

Comment: @Richard - yes, that would indeed fit within the given requirements. You could debate that the Phoenix is a separate character who isn't Earth-based, but I won't do that.

Comment: @JackBNimble - the other question was asking for any character out of the entire DC and Marvel catalogs. I think we can probably agree that my question is much more specific than that.

Comment: @JackBNimble well, for one, "not constructive" is no longer a close reason. i'm not really sure any of the close reasons really apply perfectly here.

Comment: You explicitly excluded him, but the answer would surely be Thanos - he killed half the universe with the snap of his fingers in the original Infinity Gauntlet mini series.  That they were restored to life later is outside the parameters of the question.

Comment: @VBartilucci - yeah, I figured if I included him or Galactus they'd skew the answer. There are other cosmic-based entities that have destroyed entire realities, so I felt it would be more in-scope if I limited it to Earth.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Primary Victory: [Dark Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Phoenix_Saga) (Jean Grey of Earth): 5 billion souls by destroying a star.

> - When Mastermind kills Cyclops' psychic image, it breaks his hold over Jean's psyche and shatters the final barriers on her power. Experiencing this power in its totality overwhelms Jean, and she renames herself "Dark Phoenix". Enraged at Mastermind, she uses a telepathic illusion to make him experience godhood, driving him insane.
> - To break her ties with her less powerful identity as Jean Grey, she strikes down the X-Men and departs for a distant galaxy. However, her power proves to be far more limited than she thought; the interstellar trip leaves her almost completely drained.
> - To recharge, she devours the energy of the nearby D'Bari star, causing a supernova which kills the entire population of the only civilized planet orbiting the star.

[image]

[image]

#### Dual Victory, [Cassandra Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra_Nova) and The Sentinels destroy [Genosha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genosha): Body Count - 16 million Genoshans. Nobody kills mutants better. (tm)

> - By New X-Men #115, Genosha had a population of sixteen million mutants and a stable, advanced society. However, the entire island was reduced to rubble and its mutant population was slain by Cassandra Nova's Wild Sentinels. There were few survivors, many evacuated, and the Brotherhood of Mutants turned one of the Sentinels into a memorial statue in #132.

[image]

Comment: Works for me - I'd completely forgotten about Genosha. Accepted!